# Craft 3 plugin - how to update entry with field of Entries type

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, php, elementquery, element

Using PHP, I want to update a field of `Entries` type of an existing entry.

Fields of type `Text` and `Number` will update with the following code:

```
$entry = Entry::find()->id($entryId)->one();
$entry->textField = 20; // works
$entry->entriesField = Entry::find()->id($relatedEntryIds)->all(); // doesn't work
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
```

I looked into the source code and it seems to be expecting a `craft\elements\db\EntryQuery` object but I can't get it to work.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok this was easy.  Tried it at first but didn't work and was successful after another go.  All it needed was a array of `Entry IDs`.

Working code:

```
$entry = Entry::find()->id($entryId)->one();
$entry->setFieldValue('textField', 20);
$entry->setFieldValue('entriesField', [$relatedEntryId1, $relatedEntryId2]);

Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the docs at https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/element-types.html#saving-custom-field-values

> When saving values on a custom field, always use the `setFieldValue()` or `setFieldValues()` methods rather than directly accessing the field handle as a property on the element object. This ensures the value is normalized and marked as dirty for delta saves.

```php
$entry->setFieldValue('testField', 'foo');
$entry->setFieldValue('entriesField', [$relatedEntryId1, $relatedEntryId2]);

Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yes this works with the latest Craft versions but unsure that it was documented in the past.  Answer edited.